# Delete duplicate

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I am writing a function that removes duplicates from an unsorted list.
This is the code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item=None):
        self.item = item
        self.next = None


class Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        current_node = self.head
        while (current_node.next):
            current_node = current_node.next

        current_node.next = new_node

    def pre_append(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def delete(self, value):
        current = self.head
        if current is None:
            return
        while (current.next is not None):
            if (current.next.data == value):
                current.next = current.next.next
                return
        if current.data == value:
            current = current.n
    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        listOfNodes = []
        while node:
            listOfNodes.append(node.item)
            node = node.next
        print(listOfNodes)
    def remove_dups(self):
        node = self.head
        prev = node.next
        values = []
        while node is not None:
            if node.item in values:
                print(node.next)
                node.next = node.next.next
            values.append(node.item)
            node = node.next







if __name__ == "__main__":
    duplicated = Linked_List()
    duplicated.append(1)
    duplicated.append(5)
    duplicated.append(8)
    duplicated.append(5)
    duplicated.append(4)
    duplicated.remove_dups()
    duplicated.print_list()
```

The output instead of being
[1, 5, 8, 4]
is
[1, 5, 8, 5]
Can someone please explain to me why? I can't understand the issue since I stated on the code that node.next should be equal to node.next.next .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `set()` instead to remove duplicates and get unique value.

Comment: @PCM it's a linkedlist what does set() has to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is:

```
while node is not None:
    if node.item in values:
        print(node.next)
        node.next = node.next.next
    values.append(node.item)
    node = node.next
```

Consider what happens when you reach the second `5` in `[1, 5, 8, 5, 4]`:

- `if node.item in values` is True, so you set `node.next` to `node.next.next`, effectively skipping the *next* item (the `4`), *not* the current one.
- You append `node.item` to `values`, adding the duplicate value `5` to the output list.
- You move to `node.next`, skipping over the next value (the `4`).

One thing you could do is inspect the next node instead of the current one so you can skip over it without navigating to it, such as (untested code):

```
while node is not None:
    if node.next.item in values:
        node.next = node.next.next
    values.append(node.item)
    node = node.next
```

Note that this won't handle a chain of duplicates and you may need an extra loop in there to find the next non-duplicate node. My example is for demonstration only.

Comment: so node.next = node.next.next is skiping 4 instead of 5 right?

Comment: Yes. The node you are currently inspecting is the duplicate one that should be skipped. If you find it's a duplicate then the *previous* one needs to have its `next` pointer updated and you need to skip straight to the current node's `next`. To make life easier you probably want to look ahead and inspect the next one instead of inspecting the current one. I'll write a quick example.

Comment: no problem i figure it out thank you very much

Comment: i made this prev = self.head
        node = prev.next

        values = []
        while node is not None:
            if node.item in values:
                prev.next = prev.next.next

            values.append(node.item)
            node = node.next
            prev = prev.next
and it seems to be correct